Creating an OverlayEntry in initState(), and accessing it from build()
My requirement is to create an OverlayEntry, and then, using a Timer, to manipulate it to move it around the screen.
I am creating the OverlayEntry, and associating it with a GlobalKey, in initState().
Both the GlobalKey and OverlayEntry are being stored in a Map. Am using a Map because there will be several OverlayEntry objects. The GlobalKey is required so that I can get the RenderBox for the OverlayEntry, so its dimensions will be available.
The problem is that the map is empty at the time the build() method runs. I am expecting initState() to have run before build().
The simplified code is as follows:
GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
Map<GlobalKey, OverlayEntry> mapForOverlayEntries =
      <GlobalKey, OverlayEntry>{};

class TestMoving extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestMoving({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestMoving> createState() => _TestMovingState();
}

class _TestMovingState extends State<TestMoving> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
       OverLayEntry overlayEntry = createOverlayEntryAndAssociateWithGlobalKey();
       final overlay = Overlay.of(context);
       overlay.insert(overlayEntry);
       mapForOverlayEntries.putIfAbsent(globalKey, () => overlayEntry);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // At this point, mapForOverlayEntries.keys.length == 0.
    // I need the OverlayEntry to have been created at this point
    return const Placeholder();
  }

It is not possible, as far as I can see, to get the RenderBox for the OverlayEntry in initState(), because there globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() will fail, as currentContext is null.
If, in initState(), I remove WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback,  the following error is thrown:
flutter: Error :  setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building.

The same error is thrown is the OverlayWidget is created within build().
If anyone can help, it is mighty appreciated.
Thanks

what do you need that global key for? and why do you need a Map if there is only one entry in it?

Have edited the question to clarify these points.

Ok, if you want multiple top widgets why don't you use one overlay with a Stack having multiple children?

That won't work here, I want the overlays moving around the screen independent of one another.

If I could get the above to work, it would appear to be much simpler than using animations

@pskink Thanks very much for the example you have provided.
